# Read locked Azure DevOps variables from .Net Core applicatoin

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nunit

I have a release pipeline in Azure DevOps, one of the steps is running test designed using Nunit.

YAML of task:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    projects: '**/a/Tests.dll'
    custom: vstest
    arguments: '--logger:"trx;LogFileName=test.trx" '
```

In my tests Setup I am retrieving few settings from Environment variables using:

```
private static IConfiguration InitConfiguration()
{
  var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
      .AddEnvironmentVariables()
      .Build();
  return config;
}
```

I am also storing the values of my environment variables in Azure DevOps variable groups.

Everything works fine when my variables are not locked, they are retrieved successfully and tests run fine.

[image: Azure DevOps variables]
However when I lock the secret ones their value comes empty hence my tests fail to run.

[image: DevOps variables]

What should I change in order for locked variables to be correctly read from my application.

Answer (score 2):

By default variables are mapped into environment variables, but when you locked them you actually make them secrets. And to have secret maps as environment you must map them explicitly. Take a [look on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables)

```yaml
variables:
 GLOBAL_MYSECRET: $(mySecret) # this will not work because the secret variable needs to be mapped as env
 GLOBAL_MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(nonSecretVariable) # this works because it's not a secret.

steps:

- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Using an input-macro works: $(mySecret)"
    Write-Host "Using the env var directly does not work: $env:MYSECRET"
    Write-Host "Using a global secret var mapped in the pipeline does not work either: $env:GLOBAL_MYSECRET"
    Write-Host "Using a global non-secret var mapped in the pipeline works: $env:GLOBAL_MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR" 
    Write-Host "Using the mapped env var for this task works and is recommended: $env:MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(mySecret) # the recommended way to map to an env variable

- bash: |
    echo "Using an input-macro works: $(mySecret)"
    echo "Using the env var directly does not work: $MYSECRET"
    echo "Using a global secret var mapped in the pipeline does not work either: $GLOBAL_MYSECRET"
    echo "Using a global non-secret var mapped in the pipeline works: $GLOBAL_MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR" 
    echo "Using the mapped env var for this task works and is recommended: $MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(mySecret) # the recommended way to map to an env variable
```

So if you want to have secret available in one task you need to add something like this:

```yaml
env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(mySecret)
```

And you need to do this for each secret separately.

With classic it is the same. You need to map them here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what about non YAML tasks?

Comment: It is the same. You also need to map them. In above link there is tab which refer to classic pipelines. I also edit my reply.